# Get value from multidimensional array in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following array in Swift:

```
var words = [
        "English" : ["Hello", "Bye"],
        "Spanish" : ["Hola", "Adios"]
    ]
```

How can I get the value for index, something as the following doesn't work

```
print(words["English"][0])
```

It throws the error: Value of optional type Array? not unwrapped, did you mean to use ! or ? but that just makes it:

```
print(words["English"]?[0])
```

and still doesn't work, please help.

Comment: It looks fine. what's the problem?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Does the error disappear changing the `?` to a `!`?

Comment: @rmaddy - Yeah, I realized that and deleted my comment. OP really needs to define "still doesn't work". :)

Comment: you want the values under English ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into how to [unwrap optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html). For example, what you are trying to do could be done either of these two ways:

Force unwrapping:

```
print(words["English"]![0])
```

Safe unwrapping:

```
if let hello = words["English"]?[0]{
    print(hello)
}
```

Comment: print(words["English"]![0]) worked. Thank you @WMios